# Moment.js: Workout the store opening and closing hours

Tags: javascript, momentjs

With Moment.js I'm trying to detect store opening and closing time but No matter how much I look into documentation and swap functions around I get `false` response from `isBefore()` & `isAfter()`

```
m.opening=[
     moment('11:30', "HH:MM"),
     moment('01:30', "HH:MM") //1:30AM the next day
];
console.log(m.opening[1].isBefore(moment('07:00', "HH:MM"))); //always false no matter if I use isBefore() or isAfter()

if(m.opening[1].isBefore(moment('7:00', "HH:MM")))
  m.opening[1].add(1,'day'); //If closing time is before 7AM add a day
  m.range =  m.moment.range(m.opening);
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: ` moment('01:30', "HH:MM") //1:30AM the next day` -- How does this become the next day?

Comment: im hoping with `m.opening[1].add(1,'day');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your values are not being set to what you think they are.

I added a sanity check and discovered that `m.opening` is an array with two null values.

Which took me to reading the documentation and you are passing in the wrong string to parse the time.  The string you want is `HH:mm`, not `HH:MM`.

I've included a snippet below, both with your code and with a working example.

Double checking that values are what you expect should always be one of the first debugging steps.

```js
var m = {};

m.opening=[
     moment('11:30', "HH:MM"),
     moment('01:30', "HH:MM") //1:30AM the next day
];


console.log(m);

console.log(m.opening[1].isBefore(moment('07:00', "HH:MM"))); //always false no matter if I use isBefore() or isAfter()


//////////////
m.opening=[
     moment('11:30', "HH:mm"),
     moment('01:30', "HH:mm") //1:30AM the next day
];


console.log(m);

console.log(m.opening[1].isBefore(moment('07:00', "HH:mm"))); // Now returns true.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.13.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```